# How to pass subarrays to multiprocessing workers with starmap

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, worker

I am trying to parallelize the processing on a numpy array. I would like to divide the array in subarrays and send each array to its multiprocessing worker (number of cpus-1). The following code works well and each worker receive a slice of the array (indices of the array) in function f:

```
pool.map_async(f, [slice(i, i + step) for i in range(start, stop, step)])
```

I tried a similar approach with starmap_async because I need to send more parameters to the function. Here the list of start and end pixel of the subarrays (mats) is made in a separate statement. However in this case only one worker is activated and the whole list is submitted to it (not just the first element).

```
mats = [(i, i + part) for i in range(0, shp[1], part)]
pool.starmap_async(f, [(mats, 0.4, 0.9, shp, shp_o)])
```

Is this a feature of the starmap function or I am not doing it correctly? Any comments appreciated.

Comment: `starmap` only unpacks the first iterable. As-written, you have a list with a single item (a tuple). Star unpacks the list returning a single result so pool only launches a single worker to pass the result to.

Comment: Assuming everything else is set up correctly, you should be able to use `pool.starmap_async(f, [(m, 0.4, 0.9, shp, shp_o) for m in mats])`

Comment: Great! Now it works. Thank you very much!